# Is it ok for an examiner to hide exam reviews

Tags: university, exams, qualifying-exam

We recently had our final exam for our bachelor degree and most of us haven't passed it, despite all the hard work we've put into it and the difference in our expectations for the results.

We asked for the reviews of the exams so that we can be better prepared for the next time we attend the exam, but we were declined that right with no clear explanation why. We presented our concerns regarding the the really short time the examiners were able to review the exams (it took them less than 2 days for the works of all the students graduating this year), in which some of the examiners responded with shouting in a really unacademic and aggressive manner.

We also heard about graduates who have had the same problem 2 or 3 years ago, and after making a little noise about it, their assessments have drastically changed in a positive way.

In the rules of our university, there isn't anywhere a rule for not giving review on the examined works, so we have sent a request to the rector of the university for letting us see the reviews of the exams, but we haven't received an answer yet.

My question is, is it ok for the examiners to hide the reviews of our works, and what can we do so that we get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Could you please specify which country this is? Rules and expectations can vary significantly between countries

Comment: Sofia, Bulgaria.

Comment: Normally this sort of behavior by professors is a sign of wishing to hide their own incompetence.

Comment: You state "We asked for the reviews of the exams [...], but we were declined that right." If it is a *right*, then you should be able to point the person in question to the place where it is *declared a right*. If there is no such place, then you don't have a *right* to it in the legal sense, though one can probably argue that it would be the "right thing to do" for the professor to give you feedback.

Comment: It's more of a subjective view. Anyone can hardly argue that we have that right.

Comment: Your language is making it hard to understand a couple of points. Do you mean 'right' in the sense that the university rules explicitly say you have a right to see your paper? When you say 'there isn't anywhere a rule...' do you mean no rule says you definitely can see your paper, or that preventing you seeing the paper is actively against the rules?

Comment: Personally I'd suggest not talking funrther about the marking time until after you've done all you can to see the marked scripts. There may or may not be a problem there, but you cannot prove it either way, unless you can demonstrate that the exams were incorrectly marked. Pointing to the length of time will only serve to aggravate the examiners, who seem to be worried about getting into trouble (whether or not they deserve to).

Answer (score 1):

My personal view is that you should be able to get feedback on your exam, though that doesn't necessarily imply getting a marked-up copy of it. But that is a personal view and whether there are rules or not at your university, the personal views of your professors hold more weight than mine.

It may be that there is some fear that giving you this material will make future use of the questions impossible - security through obscurity.

But what is OK in one place is forbidden in others.

But you are more likely to be successful if you ask for *feedback* on your performance. It is hard to argue that you are not entitled to that.

I doubt that there is fear that you have been too harshly judged in the grading, but there may be a reluctance to do anything that might generate such a charge.

But, as you are aware, without feedback you have no way forward other than blindly guessing.

One possibility is that your grades are being reviewed by a higher authority and so there is a delay. If making a bit of noise has been effective in the past, you might be able to successfully call for a higher level review without seeming like malcontents.

Comment: Well, We surely don't want a copy of the exam. All the graduation exams from past years are publicly available on the site of the faculty. We just want some feedback regarding our works.